# Cannot extend built-in Date class in NodeJS 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

in a module intended to be used in NodeJS 6.* I have written a class that extends the built-in Date class by some useful methods.

```
class DateEnhanced extends Date { 
  ... some new methods here ...
}
```

Everything works fine in NodeJS 6.* because it implements all ES6 features.

Now I am trying to recode the class for NodeJS 4 but I get stuck when I apply the classical inheritance pattern:

```
function DateEnhanced () { return Date.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments ); }
DateEnhanced.prototype = Object.create( Date.prototype );
DateEnhanced.prototype.constructor = DateEnhanced ;
```

Everything works fine as long as I only create the objects.  However, as soon as I want to use Date methods, I get a problem:

```
let d = new DateEnhanced() ;
let h = d.getHours();
```

causes an exception:

```
TypeError: this is not a Date object.
at D.getHours (native)
```

I tried various modifications in the pattern but nothing works.  What should I do?

Comment: You cannot extend builtins with the classical ES5 pattern - it doesn't work e.g. for Arrays either. You can use a hack with `__proto__`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. As an off-topic I would like to ask someone from StackOverflow to check the search algorithm because the reason why I actually asked this question was that several search attempts did not return any relevant question asked previously.

Comment: Go to the link where the question already has an answer and check my recently added post...it works.